# Coq: Prove equality of two factorial functions using induction

Tags: functional-programming, coq, factorial

I want to prove that two factorial functions are equivalent in Coq using induction.

The base case `n = 0` is easy, however, the induction case is more complicated. I see, that if I could rewrite `(visit_fac_v2 n' (n * a))` to `n * (visit_fac_v2 n' a)`, I would be done. However, translating this idea into Coq causes me troubles.

How would one go about proving this in Coq?

```coq
Fixpoint fac_v1 (n : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => 1
  | S n' =>  n * (fac_v1 n')
  end.

Fixpoint visit_fac_v2 (n a : nat) : nat :=
  match n with
  | 0 => a
  | S n' => visit_fac_v2 n' (n * a)
  end.

Definition fac_v2 (n : nat) : nat :=
  visit_fac_v2 n 1.

Proposition equivalence_of_fac_v1_and_fac_v2 :
  forall n : nat,
    fac_v1 n = fac_v2 n.
Proof.
Abort.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical thing to do when proving that a direct-style function and its accumulator-based equivalent are equal is to state a stronger invariant which ought to be true for any value the accumulator may hold.

You can then specialise it to the value the function is called with thus obtaining the statement you are interested in as a corollary of the more general one.

The general statement here is as follows:

```
Theorem general_equivalence_of_fac_v1_and_fac_v2 :
  forall n a : nat,
    a * fac_v1 n = visit_fac_v2 n a.
```

And its proof is fairly straightforward (you do have to be careful and ensure that `induction` comes before `intro a` because you want the induction hypothesis to be valid for *any* `a`):

```
Proof.
intros n; induction n; intro a.
 - simpl ; ring.
 - simpl ; rewrite <- IHn ; ring.
Qed.
```

Your proposition is a direct consequence of this more general theorem.

Comment: What is "simpl" and "ring"?

Comment: Tactics. `simpl` computes in the goal and `ring` solves equalities on a ring.

Comment: Would it be possible to rewite the proof only using "rewrite" and "apply"?

Comment: To be a bit more precise: `ring` also solves equalities on [semirings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), which `nat` is an instance of. To use the `ring` tactic we'd need `Require Import ArithRing.` or `Require Import Arith.`, since the latter exports the former.

Comment: @Shuzheng Sure: instead of proving the equalities using `ring`, you can rewrite or apply lemmas stating the properties of `(*)` (e.g. `apply PeanoNat.Nat.mul_1_r` can replace the first call to `ring`.). It's just going to be a bit more annoying.

Answer (score 1):

In the inductive case, you can apply the induction hypothesis and simplify the goal to:

```coq
visit_fac_v2 n 1 + n * visit_fac_v2 n 1 = visit_fac_v2 n (S n)
```

To prove this, you can use the following lemma:

```coq
Lemma visit_fac_v2_extract:
  forall n a : nat,
    visit_fac_v2 n a = a * visit_fac_v2 n 1.
```