# Coq verification of factorial program through two implementations

Tags: functional-programming, coq, verification

I am newbie to `coq` and I am trying to verify the functionality of `factorial` program.

From my understanding, what I should do is to follow the standard `Hoare Logic` paradigm, start from the precondition, figure the loop invariant, and reason the postcondition. Something like this:

```
{{ X = m }} 
{{  FOL 1 }}
Y ::= 1;;
{{  FOL 2   }}
WHILE !(X = 0) DO  
    {{ FOL 3    }}
    Y ::= Y * X;;
    {{ FOL 4   }}
    X ::= X - 1
   {{ FOL 5  }}
END
{{ FOL 6 }}
{{ Y = m! }}
```

Here the `FOL` standards from "first order logic".

However, to my surprise, it seems that when verifying the `factorial` program with `coq`, the common way is to define the following two functions `fact` and `fact_tr`:

```
Fixpoint fact (n:nat) :=
match n with
| 0 => 1
| S k => n * (fact k)
end.

Fixpoint fact_tr_acc (n:nat) (acc:nat) :=
match n with
| 0 => acc
| S k => fact_tr_acc k (n * acc)
end.

Definition fact_tr (n:nat) :=
fact_tr_acc n 1.
```

and future proof the equivalence of these two functions:

```
Theorem fact_tr_correct : forall n:nat,
fact_tr n = fact n.
```

I learned such approach from [here](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2017fa/l/23-coq-verification/lec.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40571546/coq-prove-equality-of-two-factorial-functions-using-induction).

So here is my question:

1. Can someone illustrate the motivation behind such "equality-based" verification approach? Are they still conceptually similar to the standard `Hoare Logic` based reasoning?
2. Still, can I use `coq` to verify the correctness of `factorial` program following the "standard" `Hoare logic` based approach? Say by specifying the precondition, postcondition and inductively reasoning the whole program.

Comment: Your study of factorial implementation is also equality based!  your post-condition asserts that `Y` has value `m!`, but the concept of `m!` must be defined somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that the underlying language of Coq's programs belongs to the family of (dependently-typed) *functional* languages, not imperative ones. Roughly, there is no state and statements, only expressions.

The motivation behind "equality-based" approach is that *simple* functional programs can serve as *specifications*. And `fact` is certainly simple -- it is Coq speak for the [definition of factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) via its fundamental recurrence relation. In other words, `fact` is a reference implementation, i.e. in this case it is an obviously correct implementation. While `fact_tr_acc` is an optimized one, whose correctness with respect to the specification we wish to establish.

Yes, you can still verify the correctness of the imperative `factorial` program. E.g. the [Software Foundations series](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu) shows how to encode imperative programs in Coq and verify their correctness using Hoare logic. See, in particular, the [factorial exercise](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/plf-current/Hoare2.html#lab95).

Comment: Thank you Anton! For the second point, I do find the factorial exercise; however, how can I write it in `Coq` and "mechanically" verify it? Note that the "factorial exercise" is just a comment of a `Coq` program, not the code itself..

Comment: The thing is the SF book explicitly asks not to publish the solution of the exercise, so I can't do it here. But you can work through the book (I can't recommend it enough if you just start your Coq journey) or you can look for the solutions on one popular git service as there are lots of people who did publish their solutions.

Comment: Thank you Anton. I do know that I can write down `Hoare logic` proof by hand, which leads to something like [this](https://github.com/tymmym/software-foundations/blob/master/Hoare2.v#L794). However, my question is that, how can I play with `Coq` to somehow "mechanically" generate/verify my proof as correct?

Comment: Or typically when we try to use `Coq` to verify the correctness of factorial, instead of explicitly write down the `Hoare logic` proof, we just go with the "equality-based" approach? Am I clear on this? Sorry for the bother and thank you a lot!

Comment: Note that proof like [this](https://github.com/tymmym/software-foundations/blob/master/Hoare2.v#L794),  they are just "comments" of a `Coq` program, they are not `Coq` program itself. Am I missed anything here?

Comment: If you scroll down a bit you'll see `factorial_dec` and `factorial_dec_correct`. The `factorial_dec` example is a legitimate Coq program. It heavily relies on Coq's notation mechanism, but in fact it's just a Coq term.

Comment: The approach you choose depends on your exact goal. If you aim is to verify imperative programs, then you can go with the SF approach. But if you'd like to extract your Coq code into OCaml then the equality-based approach seems a natural option (but not the only one in general).